# Regarding Telerik grid

Tags: asp.net-mvc

we know that in telerik grid we will use like this

```
<% Html.Telerik().Grid(Model.Terminology.Contents).Name("TerminologyCategories")
  .Columns(column =>
  {
      column.Bound(termContent => termContent.Language.Name).Title("Language");
      column.Bound(termContent => termContent.Data).Title("Text");
      column.Template(termContent => Html.ActionLink("Edit", "#",
      new { id = termContent.ID, termid = termContent.Terminology.ID },
      new { onclick = "editContentDialog(" + termContent.ID + "); return false;" })).Title("Action");
      column.Bound(termContent => termContent.Updated);
      column.Bound(termContent => termContent.aspnet_Users.UserName);

  }).Render();
%>
```

Suppose in the row:

```
column.Template(termContent => Html.ActionLink("Edit", "#",
    new { id = termContent.ID, termid = termContent.Terminology.ID },
    new { onclick = "editContentDialog(" + termContent.ID + "); return false;"     })
).Title("Action");
```

I want to use create or edit link based on termContent.Data is there or not in such case how can I use if else condition in the telerik column.template or column.bound property
can anyone guid me.
I got struct in it.please anyone can help me

Thanks
Manjunath

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want your template to be conditional, if so, then this should get you going in the right direction.

```
 .Columns(columns =>
 {
     columns.Template( 
           @<text>
           <input name="cbxStatus" type="checkbox" value="@item.status_cd" title="cbxStatus" 
              @if (item.status_cd == "A")
              {
                  <text>checked="checked"</text>
              }
              @if (item.status_cd == "I")
              {
                  <text>checked="unchecked"</text>
              }
           />
           </text>);
    columns.Bound(p => p.date_added).Width(125);
    columns.Bound(p => p.account_name).Width(100);
 })
```